# Javascript (Math.pow(2,31) | 0) produce negative number

Tags: javascript, math

It's said in JS bitwise operators are only defined for 32-bit numbers, and the safe range is `Math.pow(-2,31)` up to `Math.pow(2,31)-1`.

And one can force a number to a 32-bit signed integer using `| 0`

So I tested in Chrome's Console:

```
Math.pow(2,30) | 0
1073741824
Math.pow(2,31)
2147483648
Math.pow(2,31) | 0
-2147483648
Math.pow(2,32) | 0
0
```

Why would a positive number bitwise or 0 resulting a negative number?

Comment: overflow maybe.

Answer (score 2):

In bitwise operterations javascript operates with 32-bit ints. For which the maximum value is `2147483647` so when you exceed that number is changes to a negative value. If you do something like this in java:

```
int x = 2147483647;
x++;
```

The result is `-2147483648` which is the same in javascript. You are exceeding the integers max size when you execute `Math.pow(2,31) | 0`.

Comment: Just to clarify for javascript, the value overflows after `Math.pow(2, 31) - 1` --which is `(2,147,483,647 ms)`, which is just over `(596 hours)`